# Gnome 3 on Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: installation, ubuntu-11.10, gnome3

I tried installing Gnome 3 on Ubuntu 11 through the Ubuntu Software Center, but when I start up a Gnome shell I get what I guess is Gnome 2.0 instead. The log in menu gives me a choice between Gnome and Gnome Classic, but they appear to be the same.
I have the following graphics card:

VGA compatible controller: nVidia Corporation GF108 [Quadro 1000M] (rev a1)

and I seem to be falling back to Unity 2D.

How do I get Gnome 3 or Unity 3D working?

Update:

I got Gnome 3 working, but now Unity 3D is no longer working. I tried installing Ironhide to enable Optimus support, but that didn't work, and eventually I disabled the nVidia card entirely which made it possible for Gnome 3 to work, but not Unity.

Comment: You computer may not meet the requirements for Gnome 3. Can you list your computer's specifications?

Comment: It's an 8 GB, i7 CPU, and a Nvidia Quadro graphics card. What are the requirements for Gnome 3?

Comment: @Ranjit It should most certainly work on that. What could be the problem are drivers for Quadro. Did you try with newest nVidia's drivers?

Comment: I just updated it to the latest drivers, but it still doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @Ranjit There are no clear-cut requirements. The GNOME team does provide some insight, however: [http://live.gnome.org/GnomeShell/FAQ](http://live.gnome.org/GnomeShell/FAQ#What_led_to_the_decision_to_make_3D_acceleration_a_requirement_for_GNOME_Shell.3F). Basically, any computer newer than 5 years should work.

Comment: @Ranjit was Unity 3D working, or did you fall back to Unity 2D?

Comment: I don't know. How can I tell which Unity I'm using?

Comment: Choose `Ubuntu` as the login session. Then once you are logged in, open the terminal and enter `echo $DESKTOP_SESSION`. It will say `ubuntu-2d` if you are running Unity 2D. Otherwise it will say `Ubuntu` as expected.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2022/discussion-between-iglvzx-and-ranjit)